# Changing data in a list into Datetime values

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to be able to change the following dates on this data set to this Datetime format **YYYY-MM-DD-HH**:

```
Date                
20220113T23Z   16877
20220113T22Z   15909
20220113T21Z   15204
20220113T20Z   15092
20220113T19Z   14804
...              ...
20150701T09Z   12387
20150701T08Z   12385
20150701T07Z   12445
20150701T06Z   12349
20150701T05Z   12583
```

however I haven't been able to do it successfully. If someone could let me know how I should be approaching this I would be very thankful

Comment: I'd start with `strptime()` to parse the datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using `pandas`.

The answer depends on the type of the variable `Date`. You can check the type of your Serie with `df["Date"].dtype`

If Date is type Object (string), then you can create a new variable with the format you need with `.str` accesor.

```py
df["Date"].str[0:4] + "-" + df["Date"].str[4:6] + "-" + df["Date"].str[6:8] + "-" + df["Date"].str[9:11]
```

If Date is type Datetime, then you can create a new variable with the format you need with `.dt` accesor and the function `strftime()`

```py
df["Date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H")
```

In both cases, the resulting Serie is type Object